# Replace some text in a PDF template using Prawn in Ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I am generating a PDF in Prawn using a template using code similar to:

```
Prawn::Document.new(:template => "template.pdf")
```

This works great, and I can add to the document in the normal way - however I would like to search for and replace some text that gets added from the template. Is this possible with Prawn?

Looking at the Prawn code it does the following:

```
 if options[:template]
   fresh_content_streams(options)
   go_to_page(1)
 else
   .....
 end

 .....

 # adds a new, empty content stream to each page. Used in templating so
 # that imported content streams can be left pristine
 #
 def fresh_content_streams(options={})
   .....
 end
```

So it creates a new content stream to prevent changing the data given in the template - the question is can I look into and change the existing stream with Prawn?

Comment: Seems opinion-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked about this at [Github here](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/issues/458). Apparently it is not possible, and is a lot more complex than I realized.

Comment: Yep, i looked for a way to do pdf templates some time ago, and it turns out to be pretty difficult.. the closest thing i found was to use pdf forms with something like this : https://github.com/moessimple/prawn-fillform . If you find a solution i would be glad to know !