# Find text in an existing PDF and add hyperlink to it (preferably with ruby)

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn, pdf-reader

I'm looking for a way to find text matching a particular pattern in a PDF and then add a hyperlink to it.  Ideally this would be done through ruby.  Thanks for any tips.

I've played around with the PDF-reader library and Prawn, but its still not evident that I can do what I'm hoping.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414763/detect-and-alter-strings-in-pdfs/19551997#19551997) I answered how to add highlights, with Perl. Adding links (which are annotations, too) will work the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Would love to see that in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `prawn` to write to a file ([How to edit or write on existing PDF with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9205993/1569064)), it seems, however, that that searching and replacing is not possible ([Replace some text in a PDF template using Prawn in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15262548/1569064)).

Comment: My case is simpler in that I'm not trying to replace with something different. I'm replacing with the same thing- only with a hyperlink which would merely change the color to blue and add an underline.  If I can't replace a word, then it seems I should at least be able to draw a new word on top of the old word.  I obviously don't know how to do it, but to say it is impossible doesn't sound right.